# How to access multiple services in Kubernetes using Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

We have an application and for each customer we provision a new namespace. There are two deployments running inside a single namespace:

- front-end Deployment
- Back-end Deployment

The front-end should be accessed by the users hence we are using LoadBalancer for each customer (We have a VM Based k8s cluster).

The problem is, as of now we have a few customers and when the business grows, the customers will be increasing and will be having more NameSpaces.

For example: If there are 100 Users, we have to have 100 LoadBalancers. This is not practical and can we have a single LoadBalancer instead and allow all the 100 Users to access through that LoadBalancer?

Can we do this using Ingress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, ingress is a right way to manage your case.

Generally you've already mentioned why ingress should be used - get a single entry point to the cluster and not having a lot of load balancers which is not convenient and may be expensive in cloud environment.

**Main benefits of using ingress are:**

- TLS termination
- hosts/paths based routing
- serves itself as a loadbalancer

and many more.

You can choose an ingress which fits better for your use-case. [Ingress options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/)

**Most common are:**

- [nginx ingress supported by kubernetes community](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)
- [nginx ingress supported by Nginx inc and community](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/intro/overview/)

Please consider getting familiar with [general concepts and examples of kubernetes ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

Comment: Hello @moonkotte thanks for your response. So for each namespace, I'm supposed to  create a Service of NodePort and map the Service name to Ingres? Appreciate if you could explain me more

Comment: @Dusty In general yes. You will have e,g, `ingress nginx` in its own namespace since it has its own components which have to be run within the cluster. Then you will have a service (`NodePort` is not needed since all communications will be done within the cluster,`ClusterIP` by default will work) and at the end you will have `ingress rules` per namespace/client. This will be [like this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout) OR if hosts are different [like this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting)

Comment: Thanks @Moonkotte! Understood. Accepted!

Comment: @Dusty You're very welcome!